# $ \lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_{E} \frac{f_{n}^{2}(x)}{1+f_{n}^{2}(x)} \mathrm{d} m=0 $ associated with convergence in measure

Tags: real-analysis, integration, limits-and-convergence, lebesgue-measure, measurable-functions

For $m E<+\infty$, why the sufficient and necessary condition of $\left\{f_{n}(x)\right\}$  converge in measure to $0$ is

$$
\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_{E} \frac{f_{n}^{2}(x)}{1+f_{n}^{2}(x)} \mathrm{d} m=0\;?
$$

How can we apply the theories in solving this problem?

Anybody could help?

Many Thanks.

Comment: better move this question to math.stackexchange

Comment: I agree with Fedor, better suited for Math.SE

Comment: AAww! OK, thanks. sorry for the first time, I haven't figure out the difference of two web.